# How to find the count of words (all and unique) in a column row-wise?

Tags: postgresql

I have a column in my Postgresql database named `Description` which contains text. For some analytics purpose, I want to find total number of words (seperated by spaces) - all words and unique words - in that description and set those counts in columns `word_count` and `unique_word_count`. For eg.

| id | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | What a great day |
| 2 | This is a product. It is useful |

I want to have following output:

| id | word_count | unique_word_count | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | What a great day |
| 2 | 7 | 6 | This is a product. It is useful |

The `unique_word_count` for `id = 2` is 6 because the word `is` has been repeated 2 times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### EDIT:

Not being 100% happy with my answer, I awarded a bonus for a question of my own on this topic [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/wordcount-in-a-field-all-and-unique-is-there-a-more-elegant-optimal-way).

Erwin Brandstetter (as usual) provided a [sublime answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240024/34007) - please use that instead of what I wrote below - unless your use case is very simple and even then...

==============================================================

To solve your issue I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE wordcount (id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ('What a great day');
INSERT INTO wordcount (description) VALUES ('This is a product. It is useful');
```

Then performed the following query (fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9d3ac3d01912f576fe7bb725818b6952)):

```
WITH arranged AS
(
  SELECT id, 
  UNNEST
  (
    STRING_TO_ARRAY
    (
      REGEXP_REPLACE(description,  '[^\w\s]', '', 'g'), ' '
    )
  ) AS word, 
  description 
  FROM wordcount
)  
SELECT a.id, COUNT(a.word), COUNT(DISTINCT(a.word)), a.description
FROM arranged a
GROUP BY a.id, a.description;
```

Result:

| id | Word_Count | Unique_Word_Count | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 | What a great day |
| 2 | 7 | 6 | This is a product. It is useful |

If you're new to all this, I would advise you to go through the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=28e200754033238345a58df40ee5a4c8) which shows the development of my thought processes which led to the query above.

I would advise you to put this logic into an onInsert/onUpdate trigger - it's probably fairly computationally intensive.

Comment: @Pranjal - I would advise you to put this logic into an onInsert/onUpdate trigger - it's probably fairly computationally intensive. Version 12 will allow [generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1943/) which could be a good solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I tried this solution and it worked like a charm. Only problem is that if the string array is like ['a', ' ', ' ', 'b'], then I get total count as 4 because it count spaces as well. Do you know how can I remove it?

Comment: Hi Pranjal, and thanks for the correct answer! I've looked at your problem string, and it appears very tricky - I've got as far as [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=309e5bea7575a7c903b6afc137671ae5) but I'm out of ideas as the minute. I **do** have to put bread on the table! :-) Maybe you could ask another question pointing back to this one? I think the dollar quotes may be the key? BTW, +1 for an interesting and thought-provoking question - I learnt a lot answering it. Oh, and if I didn't say it before, welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Hi again Pranjal - I've solved it! I'm like a dog with a bone once I get my teeth into a problem! :-) I'm actually going to post it as a new question, because I don't feel that my solution is very elegant and I want to ask the "real" gurus here if it's an optimal approach. I'll let you know when it's asked.

Comment: Hi again Pranjal - you might be interested to know that I've posted a solution to your ` ['a', ' ', ' ', 'b']` string problem [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239958/wordcount-in-a-field-all-and-unique-is-there-a-more-elegant-optimal-way/239961#239961) in case you're interested! In fact, I got into it so much, I'm going to offer a bonus - as I said, I really learnt a lot. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the supplementary question. All this is pretty much new to me but I am so much enjoying learning these new things. Thank you once again for such a wonder solution and the follow up question :)